# How to format Text bold from a String in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-text

i have this example code:

```
let longString = """

imagine here is a really really long Text. **This is in bold**. This is not in bold
"""

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
       
            Text(longString)
     
    }
}
```

But this is not working. I get the Text with the ** in the View, but I want it in bold.

If I do this:

```
Text("imagine here is a really really long Text. **This is in bold**. This is not in bold")
```

This works.

Why is that and how I can use bold Text from a String in this case?

Thank you for taking your time to help me

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-render-markdown-content-in-text

Answer (score 1):

The version with the string literal is going to `Text.init(LocalizedStringKey, tableName: String?, bundle: Bundle?, comment: StaticString?)`, in other words, the string literal is being handled as a `LocalizedStringKey`.

If you want to use a property instead of a string literal then you need to convert it to a `LocalizedStringKey` explicitly:

```swift
Text(LocalizedStringKey(longString))
```