# Text modifiers in Data

Tags: swiftui, swift3

I've created a data-model in SwiftUI

```
import Foundation
struct BLSectionModel : Identifiable {
var descriptionTop : String
}
```

The data looks as follows:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

let blSectionsDataV1 : [BLSectionModel] = [
bulletDescription: "I want to have multiple \(Text("**formats**")) for text in the _same **text box**_ at the same time even if it is really \(Text("_really_ **really _really_** ~~really~~")) long text so it would need to wrap correctly and maybe even include \(Text("[links](https://www.apple.com)!)")) to another website")
]
```

the code runs without an (obvious) error but all I see is

all I get on the view is
I want to have multiple Text(storage:
SwiftUI.Text.Storage.anyTextStorage(: "formats"), modifiers: [1) for text in the _same **text box** at the same time even if it is really
Text(storage:
SwiftUI.Text.Storage.anyTextStorage(<Lo
calized TextStorage:
0x000060000156cf50>: "really really
really really"), modifiers: []) long text so it would need to wrap correctly and maybe even include Text(storage:
SwiftUI.Text.Storage.anyTextStorage(: "links!)"), modifiers: []) to another website

But I want to have

I want to have **multiple** for text in the *same **text box*** at the same time even if it is really (Text("*really* **really *really***

```html
<s>really<s>
```

")) long text so it would need to wrap correctly and maybe even include (Text("[links](https://www.apple.com)!)")) to another website")

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your code doesn't compile, nor do you show how you are actually displaying the data. But I think I get the general idea. The key to getting it to display the text with the formatting is to convert it to `LocalizedStringKey` (see [How to format Text bold from a String in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75836889/how-to-format-text-bold-from-a-string-in-swiftui) for more explanation).

Here is a working example based on your snippets:

```swift
struct BLSectionModel : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var descriptionTop : LocalizedStringKey
}

struct ContentView: View {
    private let blSectionsDataV1 : [BLSectionModel] = [
        BLSectionModel(
            descriptionTop: "I want to have multiple \(Text("**formats**")) for text in the _same **text box**_ at the same time even if it is really \(Text("_really_ **really _really_** ~~really~~")) long text so it would need to wrap correctly and maybe even include \(Text("[links](https://www.apple.com)!)")) to another website"
        )
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(blSectionsDataV1) { data in
                Text(data.descriptionTop)
            }
        }
    }
}
```